# Convert AFJsonRequestOperation setUploadProgressBlock from AFNetworking 1.6 to AFNetworking 3.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, migration, afnetworking, afnetworking-3

Is that possible to rewrite following code used AFNetworking v 1.6:

```
__block AFJSONRequestOperation *operation =
[AFJSONRequestOperation
 JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
 success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
     [self uploadFinished:JSON completionBlock:completion failureBlock:failure];
 }
 failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
     [self uploadFailedWithError:error completionBlock:completion failureBlock:failure];
     [UIApplication hideProgressLoading];
 }];
[operation
 setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
     [UIApplication updateProgress:totalBytesWritten * 1.0/totalBytesExpectedToWrite];
 }];
[operation start];
```

to the AFNetworking 3.1 version?